# How to convert an Int to Hex String in Swift

Tags: ios, string, hex, swift

In Obj-C I used to convert an unsigned integer n to a hex string with

```
 NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2X", n];
```

I tried for a long time to translate this into Swift language, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Based on the answer by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986319/generate-an-integer-binary-representation-using-swift, you can do `String s = "0x" + String(n, radix: 16)`

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can now do:

```
let n = 14
var st = String(format:"%02X", n)
st += " is the hexadecimal representation of \(n)"
print(st)
```

> ```
> 0E is the hexadecimal representation of 14
> ```

Note: The `2` in this example is the *field width* and represents the *minimum* length desired.  The `0` tells it to pad the result with leading `0`'s if necessary.  (Without the `0`, the result would be padded with leading spaces).  Of course, if the result is larger than two characters, the field length will not be clipped to a width of `2`; it will expand to whatever length is necessary to display the full result.

This only works if you have `Foundation` imported (this includes the import of `Cocoa` or `UIKit`).  This isn't a problem if you're doing *iOS* or *macOS* programming.

Use uppercase `X` if you want `A...F` and lowercase `x` if you want `a...f`:

```
String(format: "%x %X", 64206, 64206)  // "face FACE"
```

If you want to print integer values larger than `UInt32.max`, add `ll` (*el-el*, not *eleven*) to the format string:

```
let n = UInt64.max
print(String(format: "%llX is hexadecimal for \(n)", n))
```

> ```
> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is hexadecimal for 18446744073709551615
> ```

---

**Original Answer**

You can still use `NSString` to do this.  The format is:

```
var st = NSString(format:"%2X", n)
```

This makes `st` an `NSString`, so then things like `+=` do not work.  If you want to be able to append to the string with `+=` make `st` into a `String` like this:

```
var st = NSString(format:"%2X", n) as String
```

or

```
var st = String(NSString(format:"%2X", n))
```

or

```
var st: String = NSString(format:"%2X", n)
```

Then you can do:

```
let n = 123
var st = NSString(format:"%2X", n) as String
st += " is the hexadecimal representation of \(n)"
// "7B is the hexadecimal representation of 123"
```

Comment: The hex and decimal numbers are reversed in "7B is 123 in hex", so the st expression should be corrected to: st = "\(n) is " + String(format:"%2X",n) + " in hex"

Comment: @KevinSliech, I'll admit that it is ambiguous.  I meant it as if someone came up and asked, "what does 7B represent ?", and you'd answer "7B is the number 123 written in hexadecimal".

Comment: I find both of those a little ambiguous, especially now that I've read both ~1000 times. Another way would be to write: "0x7B = 123d" or something like that. The ambiguity might goof up folks not well versed in alternate number systems.

Comment: @KevinSliech, thanks.  I made the statement clearer.

Comment: I think %2X should be %2llX

Comment: @lbsweek, thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer.

Comment: In Swift4 you must use "%02X" instead of "%2X" if you want leading "0" if necessary ("%2X" insert a space)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Bubu.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Note: This won't work with Doubles (1.0), Cast to Int first.

Comment: To get a zero filled UInt64 value, do this: String(format: "%016llX", n)    n=917320791915679476,  will return "0CBAFA666B36CEF4"

Answer (score 62):

In Swift there is a specific `init` method on `String` for exactly this:

```
let hex = String(0xF, radix: 16, uppercase: false)
println("hex=\(hex)") // Output: f
```

Comment: How can i convert this String to UInt?

Comment: you want to convert `"0xF"` to a `UInt`?

Comment: `let number = UInt("0xF".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("0x", withString:""), radix: 16)`, `number` will be of type `UInt?` If you need more ask a question :)

Comment: mayhap: `String(0xf, radix: 0x10, uppercase: false)`

Comment: @Rich Do we have this radix method for NSString in Objective C?

Comment: @NareshNallamsetty bit late but you'd have to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method, e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X", 0xF]`

Answer (score 55):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the three following methods in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using  `String`'s `init(_:radix:uppercase:)` initializer

Swift `String` has a [`init(_:radix:uppercase:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init) initializer with the following declaration:

```
init<T>(_ value: T, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false) where T : BinaryInteger
```

> Creates a string representing the given value in base 10, or some other specified base.

The Playground code below shows how to create a `String` instance that represents an integer value in hexadecimal format by using `init(_:radix:uppercase:)` and without having to import `Foundation`:

```
let string1 = String(2, radix: 16)
print(string1) // prints: "2"

let string2 = String(211, radix: 16)
print(string2) // prints: "d3"

let string3 = String(211, radix: 16, uppercase: true)
print(string3) // prints: "D3"
```

---

### #2. Using `String`'s `init(format:​_:​)` initializer

`Foundation` provides `String` a [`init(format:​_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init) initializer. `init(format:​_:​)` has the following declaration:

```
init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)
```

> Returns a `String` object initialized by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.

The Apple's *String  Programming Guide* gives a list of the format specifiers that are supported by `String` and `NSString`. Among those format specifiers, `%X` has the following [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1):

> Unsigned 32-bit integer (`unsigned int`), printed in hexadecimal using the digits 0–9 and uppercase A–F.

The Playground code below shows how to create a `String` instance that represents an integer value in hexadecimal format with `init(format:​_:​)`:

```
import Foundation

let string1 = String(format:"%X", 2)
print(string1) // prints: "2"

let string2 = String(format:"%02X", 1)
print(string2) // prints: "01"

let string3 = String(format:"%02X", 211)
print(string3) // prints: "D3"

let string4 = String(format: "%02X, %02X, %02X", 12, 121, 255)
print(string4) // prints: "0C, 79, FF"
```

---

### #3. Using `String`'s `init(format:​arguments:​)` initializer

`Foundation` provides `String` a [`init(format:​arguments:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126743-init) initializer. `init(format:​arguments:​)` has the following declaration:

```
init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])
```

> Returns a `String` object initialized by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted according to the user’s default locale.

The Playground code below shows how to create a `String` instance that represents an integer value in hexadecimal format with `init(format:​arguments:​)`:

```
import Foundation

let string1 = String(format:"%X", arguments: [2])
print(string1) // prints: "2"

let string2 = String(format:"%02X", arguments: [1])
print(string2) // prints: "01"

let string3 = String(format:"%02X",  arguments: [211])
print(string3) // prints: "D3"

let string4 = String(format: "%02X, %02X, %02X",  arguments: [12, 121, 255])
print(string4) // prints: "0C, 79, FF"
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5.2.4

```
let value = 200
let hexString = String(format: "%02X", value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Answers above work fine for values in the range of a 32 bit Int, but values over this won't work as the value will roll over.

You need to use the [length modifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for values greater than a 32bit Int

%x = Unsigned 32-bit integer (unsigned int)

ll = Length modifiers specifying that a following d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long long or unsigned long long argument.

```
let hexString = String(format:"%llX", decimalValue)
```

Comment: Please add code to convert hex back to decimal too.

Comment: @VarunNaharia `Int("hexaString", radix: 16)`

Comment: Hmm doesn't appear to work anymore
Argument type 'Decimal' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

Answer (score 2):

To use

```
let string2 = String(format:"%02X", 1)
print(string2) // prints: "01"
```

In Swift3 import foundation is not required, At least not in a Project.
String should have all the functionality as NSString.