# Is there a swift native function to convert a number to a hex string?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, numbers, hex

Is there any native Swift way for any (at least integer) number to get its hexadecimal representation in a string? And the inverse. It must not use Foundation. For example the String class has a function

```
func toInt() -> Int?
```

which converts a string representing an integer to its Int value. I am looking for something similar, using the hex strings. I know this is easily implementable, but if Swift has it there already it would be better. Otherwise if you made already an extension of String and Int to achieve the following:

```
let anHex = "0xA0"
if let anInt = anHex.toInt() {
   println(anInt)               // prints 128
   println(anInt.toHexString()) // prints "0xA0"
}
```

I know it isn't rocket science but in case please share it.

PS: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24229505/4243998), the difference is that it was very related to the Foundation framework, while I am not using it in my code (nor I am importing anything else) and for now I'd like to keep it in this way, also for learning purposes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790660/how-to-convert-a-binary-to-decimal-in-swift for one direction and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181221/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-to-binary-in-swift for the other directions (just replace base 2 by base 16). The first requires `import Darwin`, the latter is "Swift only".

Comment: Well, if you're not importing *anything* you're going to have trouble, but have you tried `sprintf`?

Comment: I see it now. So "String(num, radix: base)" is what I was looking for, since I am not importing anything for now. Ok, thanks. I must force myself to look at the initializers when checking the source code. This is the second one I missed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

As of **Swift 2,** all integer types have a constructor

```
init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

so that both integer
to hex string and hex string to integer conversions can be done
with built-in methods. Example:

```
let num = 1000
let str = String(num, radix: 16)
print(str) // "3e8"

if let num2 = Int(str, radix: 16) {
    print(num2) // 1000
}
```

---

*(Old answer for Swift 1:)* The conversion from an integer to a hex string can be done with

```
let hex = String(num, radix: 16)
```

(see for example [How to convert a decimal number to binary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181221/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-to-binary-in-swift)). This does not require the import of any Framework
and works with any base between 2 and 36.

The conversion from a hex string to an integer can be done with the BSD
library function `strtoul()` (compare [How to convert a binary to decimal in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790660/how-to-convert-a-binary-to-decimal-in-swift)) if you are willing to `import Darwin`.

Otherwise there is (as far as I know) no built-in Swift method. Here is an extension
that converts a string to a number according to a given base:

```
extension UInt {
    init?(_ string: String, radix: UInt) {
        let digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        var result = UInt(0)
        for digit in string.lowercaseString {
            if let range = digits.rangeOfString(String(digit)) {
                let val = UInt(distance(digits.startIndex, range.startIndex))
                if val >= radix {
                    return nil
                }
                result = result * radix + val
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let hexString = "A0"
if let num = UInt(hexString, radix: 16) {
    println(num)
} else {
    println("invalid input")
}
```

Comment: Minor correction `String(num, radix: 16)` works for bases 2 through 36.

Comment: @vacawama: Thanks, corrected. The same is true for `strtoul()` and the above extension method.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid stripping any leading `0` characters? i.e. with radix `16`, I'd like `"0F"`, instead I get `"F"`.

Comment: @charl: No, not with the built-in methods. You have to strip a leading "0" after the conversion.

Comment: Swift 3: `extension UInt {
    init?(_ string: String, radix: UInt) {
        let digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        var result = UInt(0)
        for digit in string.lowercased().characters {
            guard let index = digits.characters.index(where: { $0 == digit }) else {
                return nil
            }
            let val = UInt(digits.distance(from: digits.startIndex, to: index))
            if val >= radix {
                return nil
            }
            result = result * radix + val
        }
        self = result
    }
}`

Comment: @Oscar: Why so complicated? The "builtin" constructor `UInt("DEADBEAF", radix: 16)` works in Swift 3 as well.

Comment: Ah. Well that sure makes things much easier indeed :) Thanks!

Comment: @Martin R Can we convert four digit decimal Integer to UInt8 Hexa Decimal?

Answer (score 28):

update: **Xcode 12.5 • Swift 5.4**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func dropping<S: StringProtocol>(prefix: S) -> SubSequence { hasPrefix(prefix) ? dropFirst(prefix.count) : self[...] }
    var hexaToDecimal: Int { Int(dropping(prefix: "0x"), radix: 16) ?? 0 }
    var hexaToBinary: String { .init(hexaToDecimal, radix: 2) }
    var decimalToHexa: String { .init(Int(self) ?? 0, radix: 16) }
    var decimalToBinary: String { .init(Int(self) ?? 0, radix: 2) }
    var binaryToDecimal: Int { Int(dropping(prefix: "0b"), radix: 2) ?? 0 }
    var binaryToHexa: String { .init(binaryToDecimal, radix: 16) }
}
```

---

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var binary: String { .init(self, radix: 2) }
    var hexa: String { .init(self, radix: 16) }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
print("7fffffffffffffff".hexaToDecimal)      // "9223372036854775807" decimal integer
print("0x7fffffffffffffff".hexaToDecimal)    // "9223372036854775807" decimal integer
print("7fffffffffffffff".hexaToBinary) // "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" binary (String)
print("0x7fffffffffffffff".hexaToBinary) // "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"

print("255".decimalToHexa)   // "ff"       hexa (String)
print("255".decimalToBinary) // "11111111" binary (String)
0b11111111

print("11111111".binaryToHexa)      // "ff"  hexa (String)
print("0b11111111".binaryToHexa)    // "ff"  hexa (String)
print("11111111".binaryToDecimal)   // 255 decimal (Int)
print("0b11111111".binaryToDecimal) // 255 decimal (Int)

print(255.binary) // "11111111" binary (String)
print(255.hexa)   // "ff"       hexa (String)
```

Comment: Incredibly thorough and helpful answer! As a side note, when converting from hex to decimal string, which is what I'm doing, this code doesn't left pad the 0's on to make a whole byte. This likely won't be a problem for anyone, but it's worth pointing out just in case. Thanks again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546967/hex-string-convert-string-uint8-array-convert-string-swift-swift-2/33548238#33548238

Answer (score 19):

### **Swift 3**:

### `String` to `UInt`:

```
let str = "fcd7d7"
let number = UInt(str, radix: 16)!
print(number)
```

result: `16570327`

### `UInt` to hex `String`:

```
let number = UInt(exactly: 16570327)!
let str = String(number, radix: 16, uppercase: false)
print(str)
```

result: `fcd7d7`

Answer (score 3):

For Float, If you might want IEEE754 floating point to HEX

```
extension Float {
 func floatToHex()->String {
    return String(self.bitPattern, radix: 16, uppercase: true)
 }
}
let f:Float = 3.685746e+19
let hex = f.floatToHex()

print("\(hex)")//5FFFC000
```

Or Visa-versa

```
extension String {

 func hexToFloat() -> Float {
    var toInt = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: strtol(self, nil, 16))
    var toInt = Int32(_truncatingBits: strtoul(self, nil, 16)) //For Swift 5
    var float:Float32!
    memcpy(&float, &toInt, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: float))
    return float
 }
}
```