# Swift - How can i fetch a button image current tint color

Tags: swift

I have button in which i have set a icon like this :

self.mybutton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_remove_red_eye.png"), for: .normal)

How can i check what is current tint color of this icon and based on that i can change the tint color ?

below is full code of view controller and there is func refresh in which i need to compare the tint color and change it

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: ViewController {

    var eye: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var welcome: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.eye = UIButton(type: .custom)
        self.eye?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_remove_red_eye.png"), for: .normal)
        self.eye?.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 10)
        self.eye?.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(password.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
        self.eye?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
        password.rightView = self.eye
        password.rightViewMode = .always
        email.layer.masksToBounds = true

        email.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
        email.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        password.layer.masksToBounds = true

        password.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
        password.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func login(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @objc func refresh(){
        print("dd")

        if let tintColor = self.eye?.imageView?.tintColor{
            print(tintColor)}else{
            print("tint color not found ")
        }
    }
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```

Comment: if let tintColor = self.mybutton?.imageView?.tintColor { //use tintColor variable }

Comment: i have update the question with full code i m getting nd a tint color how to compare it with my hex string color ocde

Comment: You can get the RGBA components as an optional array of float values using the following code: tintColor.cgColor.components. These are float values from 0 to 1. First is red, the second is green, the third is blue and the last is the alpha channel.

Comment: yes got it. but why my button image tint is not getting changed even after changing the tint color  self.eye?.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the tint color of the button, based on the documentation the property is `mybutton.tintColor` of type UIColor.
If you really want to get the dominant colors of the UIImage, you could use https://github.com/jathu/UIImageColors

Comment: why the tint color is not changing i dont understand i got mybutton.tintColor how can i compare this hex string of color

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do but i use this website to get the UIColor of a hex value: http://uicolor.xyz/#/hex-to-ui

Comment: i m getting this "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0.478431 1 1" while printing my tint color how can i compare this value to my hex code which is set as "#bebebe" and if tint color value matches with hexcode how can i change button icon tint color

Comment: Check this post for example about hex and integers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings

Comment: From the website i gave you the UIColor corresponding to you hex #bebebe is UIColor(red:0.75, green:0.75, blue:0.75, alpha:1.0).  
Then you can just test it like this  
`let mybutton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
let colorA = mybutton.tintColor
let colorB = UIColor(red:0.75, green:0.75, blue:0.75, alpha:1.0)

if (colorA == colorB) {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("not equal")
}`

Comment: why tint color is not getting set on button image is it becoz i m putting button icon right of a textfield or something have i missed