# swift: hexdecimal string to double

Tags: swift

Im reading accelerometer data from an ibeacon that appears in the following string format:

```
x hex string value: "0160"
y hex string value: "ff14"
z hex string value: "0114"
```

Im expecting to see these values as double values ranging from 0g to 1g. How would you convert these hex strings into doubles in swift?

Comment: Do you really get those strings, or is that the hexadecimal representation of binary data from the beacon?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the integer value from hex string with `Int(_:radix:)`

```
let string = "ff14"
let hexValue = Int(string, radix: 16)!
```

and divide by 65535 (16 bit) to get values between 0.0 and 1.0

```
let result = Double(hexValue) / 65535
```