# How to convert convert [String] to [UInt8] in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, converters

How to convert my `stringArray` to `int8Array`. Please give me any solution to convert this.
I want below type of array

```
let int8Array:[UInt8] = [ox55,0x55,0xff,0x01,0x0B,0x00,0x0B,0x03,0x07,0x12,0x0E,0x0C,0x10,0x09,0x12,0x0C,0x19,0x09,0xFF,0x14]
```

Below is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {
var checkSum:UInt8 = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let stringArray:[String] = ["0x55", "0x55", "0xff", "0x01", "0x0B", "0x38", "0x18", "0x31", "0x10", "0x18", "0x0E", "0x16", "0x31", "0x10", "0x18", "0x16", "0x30", "0x11", "0x18", "0x20", "0xE1"]
    var int8Array:[UInt8] = stringArray.map{ UInt8($0.dropFirst(2), radix: 16)! }
    int8Array.removeFirst()
    int8Array.removeFirst()
    int8Array.removeFirst()
    print(int8Array)
    for item in int8Array {
        checkSum = calculateCheckSum(crc: checkSum, byteValue: UInt8(item))
    }
    print(checkSum)

}

func calculateCheckSum(crc:UInt8, byteValue: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    let generator: UInt8 = 0x1D

    var newCrc = crc ^ byteValue

    for _ in 1...8 {
        if (newCrc & 0x80 != 0) {
            newCrc = (newCrc << 1) ^ generator
        }
        else {
            newCrc <<= 1
        }
    }
    return newCrc
}

}
```

Comment: Do you receive these values from somewhere or are they specified in your code like that?

Comment: This values are in my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings ?

Comment: You can directly write `UInt8` instead of `String` in `stringArray`

Answer (score 0):

Just `map` the stuff, you have to remove `0x` to make the `UInt8(_:radix:)` initializer work.

```
let uint8Array = stringArray.map{ UInt8($0.dropFirst(2), radix: 16)! }
```

Comment: It shows me this output:     [Optional(85), Optional(85), Optional(255), Optional(1), Optional(11), Optional(56), Optional(24), Optional(49), Optional(16), Optional(24), Optional(14), Optional(22), Optional(49), Optional(16), Optional(24), Optional(22), Optional(48), Optional(17), Optional(24), Optional(32), Optional(225)]

Comment: I want array in this format......let int8Array:[UInt8] = [ox55,0x55,0xff,0x01,0x0B,0x00,0x0B,0x03,0x07,0x12,0x0E,0x0C,0x10,0x09,0x12,0x0C,0x19,0x09,0xFF,0x14]

Comment: I updated the answer, you have to unwrap the optionals

Comment: i have updated my code. Please check. With using this the checksum returns is different. So I want it in [0x01,0x0B,0x00,0x0B,0x03,0x07,0x12,0x0E,0x0C,0x10,0x09,0x12,0x0C,0x19,0x09,0xFF,0x14] this format

Comment: The `UInt8` representation in Swift is the same as `Int`. `0x55` is the same as `85`. The `0x..` syntax can be used only for literals.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing our checkSum value?

Comment: I don't know what the checksum code does but my answer reliably maps all string hex representations to `UInt8`

Comment: When I pass this type of data to calculateCheckSum function [0x01,0x0B,0x00,0x0B,0x03,0x07,0x12,0x0E,0x0C,0x10,0x09,0x12,0x0C,0x19,0x09,0xFF,0x14] then it returns 225 and when using this [1, 11, 56, 24, 49, 16, 24, 14, 22, 49, 16, 24, 22, 48, 17, 24, 32, 225] it shows different i.e 128

Comment: The arrays **are** different.

Comment: I need it same.

Comment: Once again if you convert a hex string array to `UInt8` using my code you will get the same. It assumes that like in the question all String values start with`0x`

Answer (score 0):

First take your string array and call `map` on it then map it to a `[UInt8]` (where the total result will be `[[UInt8]]` and call `flatMap` on the result to get an array of `[UInt8]`.. then you can do `forEach` on it to calculate your checksum or w/e..

```
[String].init().map({
    [UInt8]($0.utf8)
}).flatMap({ $0 }).forEach({
    print($0) //Print each byte or convert to hex or w/e..
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is an option you could switch it around to specify the `UInt8` array and derive the `String` array from that.

```
let int8Array: [UInt8] = [0x55, 0x55, 0xa5, 0x3f]
var stringArray: [String] {
  return int8Array.map { String(format: "0x%02X", $0) }
}

print(stringArray)
// ["0x55", "0x55", "0xA5", "0x3F"]
```

Comment: No. I don't have this option. I want vice versa.