# iTunes/Apple Music Persistent ID

Tags: swift

I am in the process of converting a Python program to a macOS app and I am now able to read the Apple Music library directly using the ITunesLibrary Framework.  I was reading the exported XML library in python and keyed all my music to the persistentID property, which I still want to do.  However, my data file that needs to be converted has the persistentID stored as a string type value because that is how iTunes/Apple Music exports the XML file. The ITunesLibrary Framework retrieves the persistentID as a NSNumber type value.

I did a little digging to see if there was a conversion method between the two so I can run a script on my data file and convert all the persistentID string types to NSNumber types.  What I found does not work.  It returns nil.

```
// The two below persistID's are for the same song.
var XMLPID = "7C9C79C87E3BEE04" // <--- persistentID from the XML file
var ITLPID:NSNumber = 8979185659088203268 // <--- persistentID from the ITL Framework

// I found this in another discussion here:
let convertedPID = NumberFormatter().number(from: XMLPID)
print("XML PID = \(XMLPID)")
print("Converted PID = \(convertedPID)")
```

Appreciate any help in getting this to work.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same number, in two representations. The first is hex (base 16). The second is decimal (base 10). Swift provides easy conversion.

```
let hex = "7C9C79C87E3BEE04"
let num = 8979185659088203268 as NSNumber
let swiftnum = num.uint64Value
UInt64(hex, radix:16) == swiftnum // true
String(swiftnum, radix:16, uppercase:true) == hex // true
```

Comment: Would it be better to use Int64 rather than Int?  I tried NSNumber but it wouldn't work.  Int and Int64 have the same result and it matches the ITLPID upon conversion.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and delete my answer below now that there is some accompanying code.

Comment: But UInt64 and NSNumber are not compatible.  I'm trying to convert the Hex16 to NSNumber, for direct comparison to what ITL framework is returning.  Uint64 and NSNumber are not comparable.

Comment: In order to compare the two as NSNumbers I added the following declaration:`var convertedPID1 = convertedPID as! NSNumber`. This allows direct comparison.