# How to convert from Octal to Decimal in Swift

Tags: swift, octal

Hi I am trying to convert an octal number to decimal in swift. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with Octal numbers in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745242/dealing-with-octal-numbers-in-swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### From Octal to Decimal

There is a specific `Int` initializer for this

```
let octal = 10
if let decimal = Int(String(octal), radix: 8) {
    print(decimal) // 8
}
```

### From Decimal to Octal

```
let decimal = 8
if let octal = Int(String(decimal, radix: 8)) {
    print(octal) // 10
}
```

> **Note 1**: Please pay attention: parenthesis are different in the 2 code snippets.
>
> **Note 2**: `Int` initializer can fail for string representations of number with more exotic radixes. Please read the comment by *@AMomchilov* below.

Comment: Awesome, do you know how you would do vice versa? Thanks :)

Comment: @user190494 Going from decimal to octal?

Comment: yup, decimal to octal. Thanks bro.

Comment: Keep in mind: Numbers don't have a radix. The radix is necessary to specify a way of formatting a number for humans to interpret. The magnitudes expressed by these string representations exist distinctly from all any radixes and string representations.

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm fairly certain that `Int` initializer can fail for string representations of number with more exotic radixes. You don't need that `Int` conversion anyway, you can just print the result of the `String(_:,  radix:)` call

Comment: @AMomchilov: yes it makes sense, I added a note to my answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert from octal to decimal easily. Swift supports octal syntax natively. You have to write "0o" before the octal number.

```
let number = 0o10
print(number) // it prints the number 8 in decimal
```

> Integer Literals
>
> Integer literals represent integer values of unspecified precision. By
>   default, integer literals are expressed in decimal; you can specify an
>   alternate base using a prefix. Binary literals begin with 0b, octal
>   literals begin with 0o, and hexadecimal literals begin with 0x.

Here is the [documentation's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html).

I hope it helps you