# Swift. Get binary string from an integer

Tags: swift, radix

I have binary `0000010` which is represented as an array of ints. From this binary I get an `Integer`:

`let number = Int32([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].reduce(0, combine: {$0*2 + $1}))` // number = **2**

but when I want to inverse operation to get a `String`:

`let binaryString = String(2, radix: 2)` // binaryString = **"10"**

So seems radix cuts some bits if they are 0, how to return 5 more zeros?

Comment: Do you really want a *string*, or do you want an array back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let binaryString = String(2, radix: 2)
let other = String(count: 8 - binaryString.characters.count, repeatedValue: Character("0")) + binaryString
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The String constructor can't know how many zero bits the Integer had **before** the conversion. You'll have to handle that yourself.

By the way, `Int` also has the radix constructor, for converting strings into Int:

```
Int("0000010", radix: 2) // Returns 2
```

Comment: Can you please explain why of `radix: 2` I mean 2?

Comment: @user2924482 Radix is the number base, in this case 2 means binary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
var binaryString = String(2, radix: 2)
binaryString = String(repeating: "0", count: 8 - binaryString.count) + binaryString
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the [FixedWidthInteger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) protocol brings an interesting example for representing the number’s binary:

```swift
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var binaryString: String {
        var result: [String] = []
        for i in 0..<(Self.bitWidth / 8) {
            let byte = UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: self >> (i * 8))
            let byteString = String(byte, radix: 2)
            let padding = String(repeating: "0",
                                 count: 8 - byteString.count)
            result.append(padding + byteString)
        }
        return "0b" + result.reversed().joined(separator: "_")
    }
}


print(Int16.max.binaryString) // Prints "0b01111111_11111111"
print((101 as UInt8).binaryString) // Prints "0b11001001"
```