# Swift - convert a large hex string to a decimal (and back again)

Tags: swift, hex, decimal

I want to convert a long hex string to a number value.  I will use the number value in a for loop.

Any ideas?

There have been some great [posts][1] on how to achieve this for small Hex strings natively in Swift (or using Foundation library).  But I could not find a post that dealt with 32 character Hex fields.

Take for example:

`4D275F68-B95B-42C1-822D-15E561163FFF`

How can I change that to a number?

**Edit** - The following articles didn't answer this question.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229505/how-to-convert-an-int-to-hex-string-in-swift`
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821112/convert-hex-to-decimal-in-swift`
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284223/how-to-convert-hex-number-to-bin-in-swift`

Comment: How large? Does the result fit into a 64-bit integer? If not, how would you want to represent it?

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for the reply.  I added an example so you can see how large.  I don't know what data type I am really talking about here as I suspect a 32 char hex number converts into a long long int.  I am trying to emulate this:  http://guid-convert.appspot.com/

Comment: Your 32-digit hexadecimal example represents a UUID, it's basically a 128-bit binary data. I cannot find any use cases for its decimal representation. What do you really want to do after you _change that to a number?_

Comment: @OOPer thanks for the comment.  I want to use the number to set the upper limit for a loop.  I want to see whether I can loop through from the lower to upper limit.  This is in the realm of "not enough computing power" but I suspect a fault in the randomness of the Database generated GUID.  

This person seems to have achieved it: http://guid-convert.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't think it's a practical use case, and I'm afraid I cannot be any help of you.