# Convert hex to decimal in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, hex

how to convert hex to decimal in swift?

I have string "423fdf4dfb1115" and I need get this => 18647576781459733.

I try this:

```
let result = UInt8(strtoul("423fdf4dfb1115", nil, 16))
```

but app crash...

I use this online convert:
http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Comment: you need to loop through the string

Comment: Why are you casting the result to an UInt8? You've got a very large number there, it couldn't possibly fit in a tiny UInt8.

Comment: the HEX number you provided (423fdf4dfb1115) is 18,596,864,257,291,000.
I proved this in excel (cell x 16^0 )and increment one additional for each digit AND summing the results for each.

Answer (score 10):

The result must be `UInt64` (`UInt8.max` is 255).

There is a convenience initializer, `strtoul` is not needed.

```
let string = "423fdf4dfb1115"
let result = UInt64(string, radix:16)
```

Comment: Cool trick. I did not know about that initializer. Will it take ANY valid radix? (Base 37, even, if for some strange reason you wanted that?) And is there a corresponding method that outputs the value of an integer class as a string in a given radix?

Comment: @DuncanC I think so. Yes, `String` has similar initializers for example `print(String(999_999, radix: 16)) // "f423f"`. There is even an optional `uppercase` parameter to get `F423F`.

Answer (score 2):

`let result = UInt64(strtoul("423fdf4dfb1115", nil, 16))`