# Converting INT64 into hex string dropping two digits?

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert an Int64 value into hex using String(format:)

Here is an example:

```
let value: Int64 = 431181030500

let stringHex = String(format: "%02X", value) //returns 64646464 instead of the expected 6464646464
```

Has anyone experienced this? Is there some other way of converting to hex in swift?

Comment: You could use `String(format: "%llX", value)`; see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229505/how-to-convert-an-int-to-hex-string-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, this works as well.

Comment: The reasoning is nicely explained in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

there is a string initializer String(radix:uppercase:) that seems to work fine.

```
String(431181030500, radix: 16, uppercase: true) // returns 6464646464
```

I am a bit concerned that String(format:) is returning the wrong value though.